# Why am I getting this error when loading the redist package in R?

Tags: r

I've recently run into an error that I have not encountered before in RStudio. I'm currently using the newest version of R, 4.1.2. I've installed a package called "redist" and when I load the package in RStudio, I get the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘redist’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'units', details:
call: udunits_init(path)
error: no database found!
```

The following code snippet ist what I used to install and run the package.

```
install.packages("redist", dependencies = TRUE)
library(installr)
```

I'm not really sure where to look for this error or how to fix this. Has anyone run into something similiar or does anyone have any advice on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Messing around with some things, I've come upon a solution that works, even though this may be related to the package itself.

Before loading the redist package, it's necessary to load the `udunits2` package. Loading the library then works.